# Getting lots of errors in Java, diagonal matrices questions

Tags: java, matrix, bluej, diagonal

I have a Diagonal Matrix and I am trying to write a function for the sum of the matrix.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.io.*;
public class DiagonalMatrices
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {

    double matrix[][] = {
                       {10,0,0,0,0},
                       {0,10,0,0,0},
                       {0,0,5,0,0},
                       {0,0,0,-10,0},
                       {0,0,0,0,7}
                      };
    int j = 0, k = 0;
    double sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0;

    for ( j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++)
    {
        for (k = 0; k < matrix.length; k++)
                System.out.print(matrix[j][k] + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
    for ( j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) 
    {
        sum1 = sum1 + matrix[j][j];
    }

    k = matrix.length - 1;
    for ( j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++)
    {
        if (k >= 0) 
        {
            sum2 = sum2 + matrix[j][k];
            k--;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Sum of Digonal elements are  :" + sum1 + " and " + sum2);





}
}`
```

I'm getting 100 errors, all saying...

"illegal character: \0"

can anyone help?

Comment: Please put the errors in your post.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is the ` at the end of source file :).

Erase it, and watch your output :

> 10.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
>
> 0.0 10.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
>
> 0.0 0.0 5.0 0.0 0.0
>
> 0.0 0.0 0.0 -10.0 0.0
>
> 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 7.0
>
> Sum of Digonal elements are  :22.0 and 5.0